# How to override plugin defined in parent maven project

Tags: java, maven

Here's my project structure

```
- parent
   - sub-parent
      - sub-module-1
      - sub-module-2
   - module-1
   - module-2
```

Now, in the pom file of parent, I defined maven plugin in pluginManagement that could be used by module-1 and module-2. And in sub-parent, I also want to define this maven plugin in pluginManagement which is used by sub-module-1 and sub-module-2.  But from what I see is that the plugin in sub-parent can not override that of parent. Could anyone help on how to override that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can include both `<pluginManagement>` and `<plugins>` with the same configuration at the same time in your module-1 and module-2 in case you are willing to override specifically their plugin configuration.

Or else the plugin configuration by default would be overriding the behavior from the topmost `pom.xml`(bottom to top) where it finds the `pluginManagement`specified.